# Как изменить код страницы HTML PHP

Tags: php, html, css, веб-программирование

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно отредактировать код страницы. Мне нужно исправить ошибку микроразметки в нескольких страницах. На главной странице ошибку удалось устранить, внеся корректировки в файл *header.php* и *functions.php* в теме страницы. Но мне нужно сделать это и на других страницах. Тема на сайте только одна.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где искать эти файлы.

**Код в header.php**

```
<html lang="ru" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article# profile: http://ogp.me/ns/profile# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

**Код в functions.php**

```
function artabr_opengraph_fix_yandex($lang) {
    $lang_prefix = 'prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#  profile: http://ogp.me/ns/profile# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"';
    $lang_fix = preg_replace('!prefix="(.*?)"!si', $lang_prefix, $lang);
    return $lang_fix;
    }
add_filter( 'language_attributes', 'artabr_opengraph_fix_yandex',20,1);
```

Comment: Ну видимо Вы говорите о WordPress, обычно если Вы вносите изменения в файл header.php, то это работает на всех страницах, так как этот файл подключается на всех страницах посредством функции `get_header();`, исключением будет, если у Вас несколько разных хедеров. Тоже самое с functions, Ваша функция отработает на всех страницах, где будет выполнен экшн `language_attributes`.

Comment: Да, я говорю о Wordpress. Я вот нашел, header-article, header-inner и header-contact. Во всех этих файлах нужно добавить тот же самый код? И functions тоже может быть несколько?

Comment: Нет, именно functions.php того что в корне темы не может быть несколько) А на счет остальных хедеров, если они используются где-то в теме, то да.

Comment: спасибо, изменил код во всех хедерах и заработало)